# Mybatis generator addRemarkComments for oracle not working

Tags: oracle, mybatis, mybatis-generator

I use mybatis generator with maven in eclipse.

I want to add comments on the generated classes, fields and methods.

I configured coomentGenerator as below but it does not add any comments.

```
<commentGenerator>
 <property name="suppressAllComments" value="false" />
 <property name="addRemarkComments" value="true" />
</commentGenerator>
```

My DB is oracle, and tables and fields have comments.

I confirmed that all_tab_comments, all_col_comments have comments for my tables and columns.

I use mybatis-generator-maven-plugin with version 1.3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle's JDBC driver does not return remarks by default.  See this page for details: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/oraperf.htm#JJDBC28785

To enable it for the generator, you must add a connection property to your `<jdbcConnection>`

`<property name="remarksReporting" value="true"/>`

Comment: Not work as well. context.addProperty("remarksReporting", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
        JDBCConnectionConfiguration jdbcConnectionConfiguration = new JDBCConnectionConfiguration();

Comment: Add it as a property to the jdbcConnection, not the context.

Comment: Thanks! I sovled by moving the mybatis generate pom source to my project, change the jdbcConnection connet code, then it works.@Jeff Butler